# Discrepancy in Time-Complexity of Bounded Halting Problem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Can you please help identify if the two following variants of the bounded halting problem are in different deterministic complexity classes?

$$
H1 = \{ (\langle M \rangle, w, t) \mid \text{$M$ accepts $w$ in time at most $t$} \}
$$
$$
H2 = \{ (\langle M \rangle, t) \mid \forall \text{$w$, $M$ accepts $w$ in time at most $t$} \}
$$
$$
\text{(where $t$ is binary-encoded for both)}
$$
When I do the math, (ignoring simulation cost for readability), I get:

- $H1 = O(2^{N}) \in $ [EXP-TIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME)
- $H2 = O(2^{N})*O(2^{2^N}) \in $ [2-EXPTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-EXPTIME)
- To illustrate my thinking, here are a few examples:

| t (base 10) | t (base 2) | N | H1 (Single Simulation) | Total Unique inputs length t | H2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 2 | 2 steps = O(2^N) | 4 = O(2^(2^N)) | 8 = 4*2 |
| 3 | 11 | 2 | 3 steps | 8 | 16 = 8*3 |
| 4 | 100 | 3 | 4 steps | 16 | 48 = 16*3 |
| 9 | 1001 | 4 | 9 steps | 512 | 2048 = 512*4 |

Resources regarding *H2*:

- [Wikipedia EXP-COMPLETE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME#EXPTIME-complete) seems to say $H2$ is EXP-COMPLETE **update below**
- [CS StackExchange EXP-Complete Example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/exp-complete-example) top answers link to above wikipedia article

Resources for *H1*:

- [CS StackExchange Halting problem in EXP-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/112686/67475)
- [A Professor's Public Lecture Notes](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Esalil/cs221/spring10/lec8.pdf) 1st page, 3.3
- [The Computational Complexity of the Bounded Halting Problem](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=7b7f3f567e60394ea0dd6733205444126dfc954e)
- [another whitepaper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.00478.pdf) page 7, bottom left
- [Wikipedia: P-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete#P-complete_problems)

---

**Update**: [wiki exp-complete article now updated to describe H1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=EXPTIME&diff=1172688891&oldid=1171074075)

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Rather than asking about multiple problems, it is best to ask about only one.  Since you want to ask about two problems, you could ask about each separately in a separate question.  By the way, the name of this site is CS Stackexchange, not CS Stackoverflow.

Comment: @D.W. - I updated accordingly, thank you!

Comment: "different resources state it differently". What resource does not agree with you about $H_1$?

Comment: @Steven - non disagree about H1 (nor do I), but some state "h2 is exp-complete", which i do not believe. (fwiw, my original question was what are the complexities of h1 and h2, respectively. I was asked to update to be a singular question, so i reworded to "whats the difference btwn the two" - sorry for confusion).

Comment: could you give a complete list of the "some"? As my current answer is saying, I think the Wikipedia case might be just an issue with the wording, rather than a mathematical discrepancy. But if you have some other sources saying more explicitly that $H_2$ is in EXP that would be quite interesting; I don't have a concrete argument to rule it out, but I believe $H_2 \in \text{EXP}$ to be a very unlikely statement.

Comment: I think your answer is the answer, I will look for more references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's simply that the Wikipedia page is a bit sloppy as it seems to be referring to $H_1$ (based on the text), even though I agree with you in that it could read as if it was talking about $H_2$. It is indeed true that $H_1$ is EXP-complete. About the status of $H_2$, I would also guess 2EXP-completeness, but the only obvious part is membership.

Comment: I think this is correct. Many resources confirm H1 complexity is EXP-Complete. Wikipedia article implying *H2*'s complexity as EXP-Complete is likely miswording / intended to reference *H1*. Will mark as answer if StackExchange community review does not disagree in next week. Thanks. *Update* wikipedia article cites [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=KMwOBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT203#v=onepage&q&f=false) which is indeed H1

Comment: I thought H2 would be in co-NEXP, because it'd suffice to show just one counter-example to refute it.